# AngularJS ng-repeat work on firefox but not in chrome and IE?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

I load some data with the $http.get

```
$http.get('toDOTasks.json')
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.tasks = response;
        });
```

then i have:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks| filter:search | orderBy: orderType() | limitTo: show" class="row">
```

and it works in firefox,but when i try chorome or IE it doesnt, what can be the problem?

Comment: Do you get some error on your console?

Comment: Yes i get: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///....JSON/toDoTasks.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. on Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of angular you are using.
With that situation, can you try it using version 1.2 because if is more compatible. Please see angular docs  [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Comment: I am using 1.4.6, but i tried 1.2.29 and its still the same, it only loads the json on Firefox, the json is loaded locally in the same directory in the project, can that be the problem?

Comment: Are you accessing it from your server like: localhost/index.html ? or just using file:// ?

Comment: Yes this seems to be the problem, i was running it from file://, i tried with localhost and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Did you find a way how to fix that in Chrome?

Comment: is there any limitations of angularjs of sum or count of ng-show commands or other ngs like ng-repeat at the same time in chrome?